# how can count rows from all tables in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, database

How can I display the number of rows in all database tables at the same time?

i dont want to write code like this

```
    public function index()
{
    $mobiles = Mobile::count();
    $users = User::where('is_admin', 'no')->count();
    $users_admin = User::where('is_admin', 'yes')->count();
    $phonebooks = phonebook::count();
    // and many tables count in here
    return view('dashboard.superAdmin.database.index', compact(
        'mobiles',
        'users',
        'users_admin',
        'phonebooks'
    ));
}
```

Is there a way to do this write in low line of codes?

Comment: gguney's answer is correct. But if you use conditionals, you need to define them one by one.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are using mysql and you can run below code to get all row counts from your database.

```
SELECT table_name, table_rows
   ->FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
   ->WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name';
```

It will give you list of your tables and their row counts

```
SELECT SUM(TABLE_ROWS)
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name';
```

Here you can get their sum